# Weather API similar to DarkSky Api

Tags: python, weather-api

I am writing a Python program that tracks how much studying people do during different weather conditions. The data I am pulling contains timestamps and the amount of hours someone studied for at that given time in the whole of Europe. I am using **a lot** of data (think 1 million rows).

I have had a great experience using DarkSky API since it provides me the weather at a given timestamp. My only issue is that DarkSky is not a financially smart API for me to use since I am looking at tons and tons of data, and it charges me for every thousand rows.

I've already looked at other API's such as (Wundergroup, OpenWeatherMap, etc.) - but they don't provide me historical data for a given time.

Anyone know a weather api that is free that can pull data for a given timestamp? Or will I have to result to paying $$$ to get the data I want

Comment: If you're grabbing 1 million API calls, there's not going to be a free solution for you. Nobody is going to let you call their service that much without asking for some $$. I would say just stick with DarkSky, since it fits your needs well already, and their pricing is competitive.

Comment: Thanks - that is what I thought but just wanted to test my luck

Comment: Actually, I just find one that might work? https://www.weatherbit.io/ they do unlimited API calls, but you're restricted to 45 calls per minute. I don't think it's ideal for yours but it's another option.

Comment: That's a good alternative. May just make 1 API call per minute for two days to get all my data haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some of the weather APIs, I think this might be useful.

**[Yahoo Weather API](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)**

Weather API provided by Yahoo. This will fetch up-to-date weather information for your location including 5-day forecast, wind, atmosphere, astronomy conditions

**[AccuWeather Enterprise API](https://developer.accuweather.com/)**

AccuWeather is one of the leading digital weather information providers. According to its website, AccuWeather provides weather forecasts for nearly 3 million locations worldwide, and over a billion people worldwide rely on AccuWeather every day. Its data is available in more than 100 languages and dialects.

**[World Weather Online](https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/api/)**

Accurate and reliable world weather forecasts, forecasts up to 14 days as well as radar, satellites and historic data. They provide some additional tool like `location search API` and `time zone API`.

**[Weatherbit](https://www.weatherbit.io/api)**

Realtime, on-the-fly adjustments, and flagging of data based on live backtesting/verification of model forecasts.

**[Australian Bureau of Meteorology API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/australian-bureau-meteorology)**

The Australian Bureau of Meteorology is the government agency responsible for providing Australians with assistance in dealing with drought, floods, fires, storms and other harsh weather conditions. The agency also provides a variety of weather, climate and water data, including real-time observations, computer model forecasts and agricultural bulletins.

**[BloomSky](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/bloomsky)**

It can export a given station's latest weather data, pictures, and time-lapse videos. This API is provided by BloomSky, a hyperlocal network of weather cameras that provides real time visual weather information from around the world.

**[Aeris Weather](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/aerisweather)**

Founded in 1996, AerisWeather's mission is to "be the most dependable weather source in the country." The company provides detailed and comprehensive weather information, including local weather forecasts, extended forecasts and weather maps.

Comment: Is darksky API free to use in production apps as well? Its docs says, 1000 API calls free for a day. I am using dark sky API in my free iOS app. I am planning to submit my app to appstore. I have attributed saying Powered by Dark Sky that will link to its website. I am pretty sure that my app will not cross 1000 API calls per day. So is it fine to use darksky API in production app as free API?

Comment: If you are not crossing the daily limit, you don't have to worry about pricing.